# How to give particular image size for the `_post_thumbnail()` function in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Can anybody can tell me how to give a particular image size to a image using `the_post_thumbnail()`?

I have also tried `add_image_size( 'image', 270, 180 );` and  Wordpress admin settings, but I'm not able to change the image size as I want. Is there any dynamic way to change the image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any of the above mentioned and can also use add_image_size function to define a new size with crop feature in yout theme function file, refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size.
you might have problem with crop for images already uploaded, but after adding image size in theme functions.php file you need to upload images to crop them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
      the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); 
      the_post_thumbnail('medium');        
      the_post_thumbnail('large');          
      the_post_thumbnail('full');           

      the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );
```

Comment: Top four are the default image sizes and last one is not giving back the proper image size (means it does not crop image properly ) .

Comment: you can set default size for 'medium','large' from admin->media section what you want is